# Rails cache not expiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, dalli

For some reason the following doesn't expire after 10 seconds

```
def rcache_value
  @random_val_from_cache = Rails.cache.fetch("random_val_from_cache",:expires_in=>10.seconds) do
  rand 10000
end
```

I output `@random_val_from_cache` in my footer of my app. Are my parameters wrong? I'm on Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that the syntax error in your example is just a typo here on SO, then the problem is likely because you're using an instance variable. The value of the cache gets set to that instance variable, which will not be reset unless done so manually, or unless the class gets reloaded (which won't happen until the server is restarted). You should do something like this:

```
def rcache_value
  Rails.cache.fetch("random_val_from_cache", :expires_in => 10.seconds) do
    rand 10000
  end
end
```

And call it with:

```
<%= rcache_value %>
```

Comment: That depends entirely on what this is an instance variable of

Comment: So how would I set an instance variable to a cached value? also, what syntax error is in my example? and thirdly, my view doesn't have access to methods in my controller...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. expires_in is deprecated in `fetch` in favor of setting it in write. So you have to write a check to see if it exists in cache already and if not then do a write